# passing array of values in a link and get them in controller method using Rails. 3

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to pass some array of values in a link_to tag in rails 3 and extract them inside one controller method using Rails 3.Please check my table below.

> payment_table.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total Claim</th>
            <th class="text-center">Paid</th>
            <th class="text-center">Outstanding</th>
            <th class="text-center">Payment Advice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= @add_payment.created_at %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= @add_payment.total_claim %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= @add_payment.paid_amount %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= @outstanding %></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                     <%= link_to "Download Pdf",download_pdf_path(:format => "pdf"),:target => "_blank" %>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the above table i have a `link_to` tag and i need to pass all table values.When user will click on that link the below action will execute.

> payments_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
def download_pdf

end
end
```

Inside download_pdf method i want to get those table values.All values may pass to one array type object and pass.My main requirement is i need those values in `downlod_pdf` method.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: pass `@add_payment` object and from there retrieve required data.

Comment: @ Gagan : Can you edit the code actually how to pass in link and getting the value inside controller method please.

Comment: user123 has answered please check it

Comment: @ Gagan: yes checking..

Comment: @ Gagan : No that is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Download Pdf",{:controller => "payments", :action => "download_pdf", :add_payment => @add_payment, :format => pdf },:target => "_blank" %>
```

OR

```
 <%= link_to "Download Pdf",download_pdf_path(@add_payment, :format => pdf ),:target => "_blank" %>
```

In controller, you can access it by using:

```
params[:add_payment]
```

Comment: @ user123 : it is giving the generated html <a href="/payments/download_pdf.pdf?add_payment=11" target="_blank">Download Pdf</a>.What is the 11 here my @add_payment has some array of value.

Comment: it is a very bad way to send a whole data through url. So instead of sending data, you should send id and find record in controller method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79042/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-user123).